# UNIX sed command help

Tags: unix, sed

```
    sed -n '$'!p abc.txt | tail +2 > def.txt
```

I have the above mentioned sed command in my code - I am unable to figure out what it does -I am going through sed tutorials to find it out but am not able to - Can some one please help me in figuring out what it does - Thanks

Comment: Is there any part of it you understand, so that we can concentrate on the rest?

Comment: I want the detail till the pipe - I am OK with the rest - Basically I want the details of sed and also I Found out sed with -n is no print - Am not sure about the remaining '$' and !p

Comment: Just as an addition to the answers: You can achieve the same result with the (arguably) cleaner delete command: `sed '$d' file`

Comment: @mhyfritz - How to use the above command for deleting the last 2 lines of the file ..?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200057/sed-how-to-delete-everything-but-the-last-n-lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking this in stages:

```
sed -n abc.txt
```

"Run `abc.txt` through sed, but don't print anything out."

```
sed -n '$!p' abc.txt
```

(Note that I've corrected what I think was a misplaced quote mark.)

"Run `abc.txt` through sed; if a line isn't the last line, print it (i.e. print all but the last line)."

I guess you know the rest, but note that `tail +2` is obsolete syntax-- `tail -n 2` would be better.

**EDIT:**

To remove the last two lines, try

```
sed 'N;$d'
```

or if that doesn't work, crude but effective:

```
sed '$d' | sed '$d'
```

Comment: `tail -n 2` would be better for GNU. `tail +2` would be required on, say, SunOS 5.10.

Comment: I used the below sed command to print all but last 2 lines Cna you validate if this is OK sed 'N;$!P;$!D;$d'

Comment: @  Beta - I am getting unnecsaary new line/CF and I am not able to import the remaining record in the DB - Is there any other way I can remove the last 2 lines - Pls help

Answer (score 2):

As far as the `sed` command `'$'!p` is concerned:

- the `$` matches only the last line of the input file.
- the `!` negates the sense of the match (so that it matches all *but* the last line).
- the `p` prints out whatever was matched.

So basically this prints all but the last line of the file.

The `-n` option stops `sed` from performing its default action (to print the pattern space) - without that, you'd get one copy of the last line and two copies of all the other lines.

The quotes around `$` are to stop the shell from trying to interpret it as a shell variable - I would have quoted the lot myself (`'$!p'`) but that's a style issue, at least on `bash`. Other shells like `csh` (which uses `!` for command history retrieval) may not be so forgiving.

Comment: I think it's more than a style issue-- most shells I know will have strong opinions about that `!`.

Comment: @Beta, good point, especially since the question isn't tagged `bash`. I'll add a snippet to cover that.

Comment: I used the below sed command to print all but last 2 lines Cna you validate if this is OK sed 'N;$!P;$!D;$d'